# Iframe scrolling doesn't work in mobile Safari

Tags: css, iframe, scroll, mobile-safari

I have a page that opens in popup (iframe) and it works perfectly everywhere except mobile Safari (iPhone 6 Plus) - scrolling doesn't work... tried with one and two fingers - still don't work. Parent window page is scrolling instead (but I do scroll a popup iframe - and can see that parent page is scrolling in the background).

I have search on that topic a bit and found couple solutions, but they don't work for me (probably because they are several years old and maybe outdated).

So here's my code:

```css
.mfp-content {
  position: relative;
  heigh: 900px;
  width: 900px;
}

.mfp-iframe-scaler {
    overflow: auto !important;  //also tried 'scroll' here
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;
}

.mfp-iframe-scaler iframe {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 999999999;
}
```

```html
<div class="mfp-content">
  <div class="mfp-iframe-scaler">
    <button title="Close (Esc)" type="button" class="mfp-close">×</button>
    <iframe class="mfp-iframe" src="/super-page" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've also tried to set these styles to body inside iframe:

```css
body.inside-iframe {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

None of these work...

Here's jsfiddle for test: https://jsfiddle.net/Ljoc7u9z/

What can I do to make scrolling work in iframe for mobile Safari too?

Comment: This is hard to debug without a link to the working code. I would like to test my proposed fix in mobile Safari.

Comment: @AndyHoffman here's fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/Ljoc7u9z/